# Lookup fields and comparison

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm finishing a plugin but have one small problem.
I'm trying to use a lookup field with a if.

When I try with the `== operator`, nothing happens. With the `Equals() method`, I got an exception saying the `object is not instantiated`...What am I doing wrong?

The plugin is executed on pre-operation when a record is created.

```
EntityReference modeleContrat = (EntityReference)target.Attributes["new_modeldecontrat"];

    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(modeleContrat.Name);

    if (modeleContrat.Name == ("Contrat d'unité"))
    {
```

Comment: With the above code the `if` is never evaluated because you throw an exception beforehand. Is that the correct code?

Comment: Hi Chris,the exception thrown was just a test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the code you put into the question is used by you to test somehow as it currently wont run due to the exception.

The error you're getting `Object not Instantiated` means exactly what it says on the tin, there is no value in your `modeleContrat` variable.

So the code should be a bit more defensive, like this:

```
EntityReference modeleContrat = (EntityReference)target.Attributes["new_modeldecontrat"];

if(modeleContrat != null && modeleContrat.Name == ("Contrat d'unité"))
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

As for `modeleContrat` not being instantiated. As your plugin is running on Pre-Create and you are retrieving the attribute from `Target` I'm assuming that somewhere your taking the input parameters out of the plugin context to retrieve it.

This is fine, however `Target` will only contain the attributes that are set on the record being saved. If you don't set it on the record, it will be null.

Comment: Hi Chris, just solved it! I didn't understand the fact that the object was not instanciated because the lookupfield is set by default according to another entity. I got an exception when trying to recover the name but not when trying to recover the id...

Comment: Glad you got it fixed :) Plugins can be troublesome to debug when theres a few kicking off

Answer (score 0):

I assume "nothing" means the logic you expect to execute doesn't. in that case the if statement equates to false.

Comment: Actually no, even if the statement equals false, some fields should be updated.